# netplan: usage by command line (without manually editing this annoying yaml file)?

Tags: command-line, netplan

It looks like netplan is the future, but compared to this simple command:

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

it's much more work to edit the annoying yaml file (the yaml parser feels like a 20 years old technology…).

**Does someone know a nice tool to modify the netplan config by just using the command line?**

Comment: If you're using a desktop machine, or using wireless, or VPN, then NetworkManager should be used. If you've got a server, which remains fairly static, then netplan should be used. Once your .yaml file is edited, generated, and applied, you shouldn't have to regularly change/edit it. Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`.

Comment: If you are using an Ubuntu version that uses netplan, it is very doubtful that your ethernet interface is *eth0*. Please double-check: `ip add show`

Comment: @chili555 thanks for your note, I really use netplan and `ip add show` displays `eth0: …`

Comment: @heynnema thanks for your clarification, but we just expect that a modern technology offers both: a configuration file, which can be modified by shell commands, too. So we can choose the more useful way depending on the situation :-)

Comment: Looks like you can use [netplan-set](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hirsute/man8/netplan-set.8.html) and then [netplan-apply](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hirsute/man8/netplan-apply.8.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ifconfig` command still exists in Ubuntu, but there is no equivalence between what `ifconfig` and `netplan` are intended to do. `ifconfig` is a tool for modifying the current state of an interface on the system. `netplan` is a tool for persistently managing the configuration of the network on a system.

If you know how to configure your network interfaces with a series of ifconfig commands, you could add a systemd unit or init script to run these at boot, but this would be less well integrated with the system's boot than using netplan.

There are presently no command line tools for editing netplan configuration.

Answer (score 2):

it turns out there are NOW cli tools for netplan to edit the configs.  these were added with https://github.com/canonical/netplan/pull/163 in September of 2020.

`netplan set` is that tool.

use `netplan get` to dump your config.

sadly this tool is very poorly documented, the extent of it is in the man page - https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/man8/netplan-set.8.html

```
netplan  set [key=value] writes a given key/value pair or YAML subtree into a YAML file in
       /etc/netplan/ and validates its format.

       You  can  specify  a   single   value   as:   "[network.]ethernets.eth0.dhcp4=[1.2.3.4/24,
       5.6.7.8/24]" or a full subtree as: "[network.]ethernets.eth0={dhcp4: true, dhcp6: true}".
```

There are a broader set of examples in the tests: https://github.com/canonical/netplan/blob/main/tests/test_cli_get_set.py

look for `self._set` lines.

For your specific example:

`ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up`

you would use

`netplan set ethernets.eth0.addresses=[192.168.1.1/24]`

This will update the relevant config in /etc/netplan (unlike ifconfig, which never modified boot config, only runtime).

You would follow this with `netplan try` and `netplan apply` to update your running system from the stored config.

You can read more documentation, such as there is, at https://netplan.io/

Answer (score 0):

You might find this page useful:

https://p5r.uk/blog/2010/ifconfig-ip-comparison.html

For example :

```
ip addr add 192.168.0.77/24 broadcast 192.168.0.255 dev eth0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this useful link!, it's a shame that new technology like netplan does not offer a command line interface.

Comment: @Tom Of course, but the 'old' technology did not offer a direct command line interface either. The ifconfig command does not alter the /etc/network/interfaces file, it modifies the configuration that the interfaces file has initialized. The netplan configuration is the same -- an initialization. The 'new' ip command like the ifconfig command modifies that configuration in place. I wonder too why those who build our systems are driven to fix things that work, but that is the world we're in and it keeps us on our toes.